# How to avoid ignorance of dependencies in android?

Tags: android, gradle, httpurlconnection

I just imported some project into my Android Studio and was testing the application on latest version of android SDK i.e. v7 but when I'm trying to test the application on old devices, the application is not working, as application consist of authentication activity which is working successfully on v7 but not on old android devices.

> org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.1'

I noticed that above dependency is getting ignored. I know that after API 23 this dependency is depreciated. Is there any method to avoid ignorance by gradle ? As my whole application is based upon **http components**.

Gradle file of application is:

**Code Updated**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.creative.nerdzprocollegemanager"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/res/values-fr'] } }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'

}
```

The Application function is :

```
@Override
 protected String doInBackground(Void...params) {
  byte[] result;
  String resultString = "";
  HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
  HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
  try {
   ArrayList < NameValuePair > nameValuePairs = new ArrayList < > ();
   for (String key: postParams.keySet()) {
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(key, postParams.get(key)));
   }
   httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));
   HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
   StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();

   if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
    errorMessage = "ok";
    result = EntityUtils.toByteArray(response.getEntity());
    resultString = new String(result, "UTF-8");
   }
  } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
   errorMessage = "Encoding is not supported";
  } catch (Exception e) {
   errorMessage = "An error occurred";
  }
  return resultString;
 }

 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
  if (errorMessage.equals("ok")) {
   sourceActivity.requestFinished(s, requestTag);
  } else
   sourceActivity.requestFailed(errorMessage, requestTag);
 }
 }
```

Is there any method to avoid ignorance of dependencies by gradle ? Or I should use some alternative to httpclient? Please suggest me some solution as I don't have much experience with android.

Comment: Add this in your app build.gradle android tag useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy' lilke android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    ...
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line in your gradle file in side android

```
android{
...
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
...
}
```

**Edit:**
Also replace

```
compile group: 'cz.msebera.android' , name: 'httpclient', version:                                
       '4.4.1.1'
```

with

```
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
```

or

```
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.1'
```

Comment: still problem is there ! Application still not working on old API's http://prntscr.com/fh93zz

Comment: No problem is still there !

Comment: try adding compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.1' instead of compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'

Comment: I tried that too ! But still the problem is not getting solved. Maybe I should should use  HttpUrlConnection class instead of HttpClient.

Comment: If its not working then issue might be some thing different and not the gradle is ignoring that particular library.